# Gatsby page query returns undefined

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby

I have a Gatsby page component and try to query some data from GraphCMS. I added the page component inside a folder:

```
/work
/work/index.ts
/work/Work.tsx
```

Work.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import SEO from 'components/seo';
import { InspirationQueryQuery } from 'graphqlTypes';
import Layout from 'shared/Layout';

const Work = ({ allGraphCmsProject }: InspirationQueryQuery) => {
  console.log(allGraphCmsProject);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Work" />
      <h1>Hi from the work page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
      <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Work;

export const query = graphql`
  query InspirationQuery {
    allGraphCmsProject {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Also I am using [graphql code generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com), to generate types for my graphql queries. Why is`allGraphCmsProject` returning undefined?

And also how to return just the `data` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `allGraphCmsProject` information it's `inside props.data.allGraphCmsProject` so the resultant structure should be:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import SEO from 'components/seo';
import { InspirationQueryQuery } from 'graphqlTypes';
import Layout from 'shared/Layout';

const Work = ({ data: {allGraphCmsProject} }: InspirationQueryQuery) => {
  console.log(allGraphCmsProject);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Work" />
      <h1>Hi from the work page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
      <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Work;

export const query = graphql`
  query InspirationQuery {
    allGraphCmsProject {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Alterrnatively:

```
import { PageProps } from "gatsby"

const Work = (props: PageProps) => {
  console.log(props.data.allGraphCmsProject);
  ... // rest of the code
```

Comment: thanks, **1)** I think it has to do with my page inside a subdirectory. If I try your example on a default gatsby page e.g `pages/my-page.tsx` it returns indeed the data. How do I query from a page within a subdirectory? **2)** It's working but I still get `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'MyTestQueryQuery'.`? My IDE also doesn't give any autocomplete, and why can't I destructure like `const SecondPage = ({ allGraphCmsProject }: MyTestQueryQuery) => {}`?

Comment: 1) Page queries only work on a page itself (top-level components inside `/pages`). In a "subdirectory" you may need to use a `staticQuery` (or `useStaticQuery`) hook or query the data in a page component and send it to the child component.
2) Said that, if you send the data from a parent component (what has the queried data) to the child, like `<SecondComponent allGraphCmsProject= {allGraphCmsProject}>` your destructuring will work